# How to install c and c++ compilers from Unix command line and then use with Eclipse?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, unix, ubuntu

Is there one command so that I can automatically install a C and C++ compiler/linker for using Eclipse on Unix?

One I have done this, when I load eclipse and I'm creating a project should the compiler now show up, or do I have to navigate and locate the compiler/linker?

Comment: What package manager are you using?

Comment: There are many possible answers to this question. Could you be more specific? Which OS, specifically? Which package manager, if not the default for your OS? Which compiler? What have you tried?

Comment: @Nur, if im honest I dont know. I have the latest version of Ubuntu? I presume I have the default package manager?

Comment: @Greg, I think I used: "sudo aptitude install build-essential"

Comment: There are a lot of factors involved. In Ubuntu, it's not too hard to get a compiler installed. In fact, it should already come as part of the Ubuntu distro. Run "g++" and see if it successfully runs a program. If so, then your compiler is already installed. Then it's a question of configuring Eclipse for your C++ project. There are a lot of different ways for that to work.

Comment: @Stephen, it would be more useful if you could elaborate on your last sentence. Thanks

Comment: In ubuntu, you would need to install 'build-essential' for gcc. You also get eclipse from the repositories. But you then need need to link the two, which I don't know how to do. If it's ubuntu and no answer here, post on programming talk on the ubuntu forums.

Comment: Well, there are a lot of ways to set up a C++ project in this world. Eclipse has all kinds of plugins for that. Most projects regardless will use "g++" as the compiler, which means your default g++ will be used. So basically you shouldn't have to do anything special to use the system-installed compiler.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -yqq install libc6-dev g++ gcc
```